# Android WebView does not work with Google code-prettify js

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm developing a simple app that can display and beautify source code. I want to use WebView and Google code-prettify to achieve this, but the result is not beautified:
[image]

I have configured the WebView with the following code:

```
WebView codeTextView = findViewById(R.id.codeText);

// JS is used to render the code
codeTextView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
codeTextView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
// Enables remote WebView debugging
// Comment these lines after it's working
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}

codeTextView.loadData(codeTextString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

, where `codeTextString` is the string of my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code-prettify/run_prettify.js"></script>
    <pre class="prettyprint"><code class="language-java">
class ABC {
    private static String codeIdToTextFileName(String id) {
        return "code_" + id + ".txt";
    }
}
    </code></pre>
</body>
```

The code-prettify library is placed inside the `assets` folder. I have confirmed that the HTML code is correct by running a HTML file with the code that is put inside the `assets` folder.
[image]

I am aware of multiple existing questions related to this problem, and made sure that:

1. The js scripts are placed inside the right directory in the `assets` folder
2. JavaScript is enabled by calling `getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

I also tried remote WebView debugging, but no error can be spotted in the debugger.
[image]

I am really running out of ideas, and any suggestion is appreciated :)